# Postgresql - Filter out data within a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data in the booking table.

booking

```
id      email                 price   type      areaid
1       person1@test1.com     70      type1          1
2       person2@test2.com     60      type2          2
3       person3@test3.com     50      type1          3
4       person4@test4.com     110     type1          3
5       person1@test1.com     90      type2          4
6       person2@test2.com     65      type2          1
7       person3@test3.com     84      type2          2
8       person4@test4.com     84      type1          2
```

I need to retrieve all email addresses from booking table which have only `type2` and no other types. According to the data, only `person2` meets this requirement.
How can I achieve this within a single query?

Comment: Please show an attempt to solve.

Comment: I tried with filtering through subquery like Rozhnev proposed but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HAVING`:

```
select email
from t
group by email 
having min(type) = 'type2' and max(type) = 'type2'
```

Comment: works prefect: https://sqlize.online/s/Z

Comment: Yes, it works . Thanks. Fastest response. You get the point.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select b.email 
from booking b 
group by b.email 
having 
    'type2'= any(array_agg(b.type)) and array_length(array_agg(b.type),1)=1;
```

You can use above query for your task.
First group by clause using email then use having clause to filter the results after get grouped.

Answer (score 1):

One more query for this problem is simple translation English to SQLish:

```
select distinct email
from test
where type = 'type2'
    and not exists (
        select email from test t2 where test.email = t2.email and t2.type != 'type2' 
    );
```

[sqlize](https://sqlize.online/s/T)

Comment: your query returns 3 distinct persons. It should return only `person2`

Comment: Strange. The answer that your accepted returns same result on provided dataset: https://sqlize.online/s/Z

Comment: You are right. Your have the wrong data in sqlize. Once I corrected them, the result was the same. So your solution works too. Thank you Rozhnev. Anyway, The Impaler was faster.

Comment: With proper indexes this solution could be faster than mine.